# how to scrape hidden input value from html using bs4 or selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hidden

Currently working on a project, my goal is to create a scraper to check the availability of item with their respective sizes (stockId) with `bs4`

Website of interest: https://www.6pm.com/p/bogs-b-moc-mid-winter-painted-black-multi/product/9419937/color/80?zlfid=192&ref=pd_detail_1_sims_cv

I’m trying to extract the data from the “only # left in stock “ and the size inside the `<input type:hidden class`.

So normally, a website will have out-of-stock on an item by default (if it's out of stock). For this specific site, the user needs to select a shoe size before the target scrape "only # left in stock” if inventories are less than 10 for that specific size autherwise nothing is scrape .

What i have done :

```
value = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'stockId'}).get('value')
    print(value)
```

Return error

My expected return is to get Each size and know “ only # left in stock “ respectively if applicable.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour], read [ask], provide the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue. easily Thanks

Comment: Can you include the code for how you're fetching the HTML and a screenshot or HTML snippet of the part/s you're trying to scrape? Anyway, I don't see anything about stock on the page, and the only `name` attributes the end with "Id" are `productId` and `colorId` [ [dev-tools inspect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CXba.png) and [code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMK8W.png) ]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of getting the 'x left in stock' data, if available on product's page:
EDIT: Here is how you can get the inputs values as well:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
urls = ['https://www.6pm.com/p/bogs-b-moc-mid-ii-burnt-orange/product/9520645/color/7595?zlfid=192&ref=pd_detail_1_sims_cv',
           'https://www.6pm.com/p/bogs-b-moc-mid-winter-painted-black-multi/product/9419937/color/80?zlfid=192&ref=pd_detail_1_sims_cv'
       ]

for x in urls:
    r = requests.get(x, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    wanted_data = soup.select_one('div[class="aU-z"]').text.strip() if soup.select_one('div[class="aU-z"]') else None
    stock_id = soup.select_one('div[class="WT-z"] > input[name="stockId"]')['value'] if soup.select_one('input[name="stockId"]') else None
    print(wanted_data, '|', stock_id, '|', x)
```

Result in terminal:

```
Only 4 left in stock | 51530929 | https://www.6pm.com/p/bogs-b-moc-mid-ii-burnt-orange/product/9520645/color/7595?zlfid=192&ref=pd_detail_1_sims_cv
None | None | https://www.6pm.com/p/bogs-b-moc-mid-winter-painted-black-multi/product/9419937/color/80?zlfid=192&ref=pd_detail_1_sims_cv
```

See BeautifulSoup documentation [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply and the exact answer i was looking for. Is there a way to get the same information for different size (stockId) in the same URL? Just because it show the result for only one size on the url. Thanks agian